# Анимация в Android

Tags: java, android, анимация, android-animation

У меня есть ImageView на котором нужно рисовать красный кружочек при нажатии на экран, нужно что бы этот кружок с определенной периодичностью менял свой радиус. (увеличивался, а потом уменьшался). Один из вариантов с помощью которого это можно сделать, это рисовать кружок на Canvas, а потом менять его радиус, перерисововая Canvas с определенной периодичностью, используя invalidate(), save(), restore(). А какие еще есть варианты, как это можно сделать по-другому?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создаете [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) с кругом, [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) в котором анимируете например увеличение круга как вам надо, затем объединяете их в [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html) и всё. 3 xml файла, капелька кода для запуска анимации и для поддержки на андройдах ниже 5го прочитайте [Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html), если в краце то просто добавьте такой код в build.gradle:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!